# OpenCV - Can't find correct contours in similar images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

the task I want to do looks pretty simple: I take as input several images with an object centered in the photo and a little color chart needed for other purposes. My code normally works for the majority of the cases, but sometimes fails miserably and I just can't understand why.

For example (these are the source images), it works correctly on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E1kQ.jpg but not on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/awBiA.jpg

Here's the code of the interested part:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
height, width, channel = img.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((31, 31), np.uint8)
dil = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
_, th = cv2.threshold(dil, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
th_er1 = cv2.bitwise_not(th)

_, contours, _= cv2.findContours(th_er1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
```

After that I'm just going to crop the image accordingly to the given results (getting the biggest rectangle contour), basically cutting off the photo only the main object.

But as I said, using very similar images sometimes works and sometimes not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try color thresholding on the background color (or foreground color) using cv2.inRange() either in BGR or HSV or LAB color space.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try not using otsu's method, and just set threshold manually, if it's possible... ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Canny edge detector. In the two images, there is a good threshold value to isolate the object in the center of the image. After applying the threshold, we blur the results and apply the [Canny edge detector](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) before finding the contours:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 190, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3, 3), 1)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 0)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=1)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)

def get_contours(img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 30)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 30)

img = cv2.imread("image.jpeg")
get_contours(img)
cv2.imshow("Result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input images:

[image]

[image]

Output images:

[image]

[image]

The green outlines are the contours of the objects, and the red outlines are the bounding boxes of the objects.